# String format for only one decimal place?

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to dispaly only one decimal place.  I've tried the following:

```
string thevalue = "6.33";
thevalue = string.Format("{0:0.#}", thevalue);
```

result: 6.33.  But should be 6.3?  Even 0.0 does not work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need it to be a floating-point value for that to work.

```
double thevalue = 6.33;
```

[Here's a demo.](http://ideone.com/W6wpU) Right now, it's just a string, so it'll be inserted as-is. If you need to parse it, use `double.Parse` or `double.TryParse`. (Or `float`, or `decimal`.)

Comment: it works perfectly but it would round the numbers like `0.155` to `0.2`..Its a small problem though!

Answer (score 35):

Here is another way to format floating point numbers as you need it:

```
string.Format("{0:F1}",6.33);
```

Answer (score 21):

Here are a few different examples to consider:

```
double l_value = 6;
string result= string.Format("{0:0.00}", l_value );
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output : 6.00

```
double l_value = 6.33333;
string result= string.Format("{0:0.00}", l_value );
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output : 6.33

```
double l_value = 6.4567;
string result = string.Format("{0:0.00}", l_value);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output : 6.46

Comment: The point is to share information and help people, I found this helpful.

Answer (score 15):

ToString() simplifies the job.
`double.Parse(theValue).ToString("N1")`

Comment: it works perfectly but it would round the numbers like 0.155 to 0.2..Its a small problem though!

Answer (score 1):

option 1 (let it be string):

```
string thevalue = "6.33";
thevalue = string.Format("{0}", thevalue.Substring(0, thevalue.length-1));
```

option 2 (convert it):

```
string thevalue = "6.33";
var thevalue = string.Format("{0:0.0}", double.Parse(theValue));
```

option 3 (fire up RegEx):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(\d+\.\d)"); // but that everywhere, maybe static
thevalue = regexObj.Match(thevalue ).Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: and what if `thevalue` would be `"6.333"`?

Comment: you can even use "Match(..).Value"

Comment: The regex and string options won't round to the nearest number, they'll truncate.

Answer (score 1):

Please this:

```
String.Format("{0:0.0}", 123.4567); // return 123.5
```