# Convert a number to 1 decimal precision

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I want to round off the given number to one decimal place but if the number is a whole number then output should have one zero after decimal.
Example:

Input:
24.66, 
**24.0002**, 
24.62

Output :
24.7, 
**24.0**, 
24.6

Comment: Did you really not Google this, before posting this question ?  This question has been asked hundreds of times before, and there's plenty of examples out there, eg :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146100/string-format-for-only-one-decimal-place

Comment: In C#? Or with jQuery (which is a *JavaScript* library)? You've tagged both, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Backs - Without knowing which the OP is using, we can't know which tag to remove. OP Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var value = 24.66;
var result = Math.Round(value, 1);
```